# Spring XD, Reactor Streams with @Configuration: NPE

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-xd

I try to implement a Reactor Stream in Spring XD without XML config:

`MyProcessor.java:`

```
...
import org.springframework.xd.reactor.Processor;
import reactor.rx.Stream;

public class MyProcessor implements Processor<MyPojo, MyPojo> {

    @Override
    public Stream<MyPojo> process(Stream<MyPojo> inputStream) {
        return inputStream.map(pojo-> {
            return pojo;
        });
    }

}
```

`ModuleConfiguration.java:`

```
...
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;
import org.springframework.xd.reactor.BroadcasterMessageHandler;

@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@ComponentScan(value = { "myPackage" })
public class ModuleConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private MyProcessor myProcessor;

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel input() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel output() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    MyProcessor myProcessor() {
        return new MyProcessor ();
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "input", outputChannel = "output")
    MessageHandler messageHandler() {
        return new BroadcasterMessageHandler(myProcessor);
    }

}
```

Furthermore `spring-module.properties` is administered.

After starting Spring XD, creating a stream and sending `MyPojo` we get the Exception

```
2015-09-08T14:50:42+0200 1.2.1.RELEASE ERROR xd-reactor-1 reactor.BroadcasterMessageHandler - Error processing stream [{push}]
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.springframework.xd.reactor.AbstractReactorMessageHandler$ChannelForwardingSubscriber.onNext(AbstractReactorMessageHandler.java:142) ~[spring-xd-reactor-1.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.rx.subscription.PushSubscription.onNext(PushSubscription.java:111) ~[reactor-stream-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at reactor.rx.action.Action.broadcastNext(Action.java:267) [reactor-stream-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at reactor.rx.action.transformation.MapAction.doNext(MapAction.java:39) [reactor-stream-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at reactor.rx.action.Action.onNext(Action.java:202) [reactor-stream-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at reactor.core.processor.util.RingBufferSubscriberUtils.route(RingBufferSubscriberUtils.java:67) [reactor-core-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at reactor.core.processor.RingBufferProcessor$BatchSignalProcessor.run(RingBufferProcessor.java:789) [reactor-core-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: reactor.core.support.Exceptions$ValueCause: Exception while signaling value: ...
```

What can we do to avoid this Exception?
By the way: if we use an XML config instead of @Configuration, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NPE` is a bug in the `AbstractReactorMessageHandler` (it should detect a null `outputChannel`).

The root cause is that the `outputChannel` must be injected into the handler. When `@ServiceActivator` is used on a `@Bean`, the `outputChannel` attribute is ignored.

Please see [the NOTE in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#d4e15193) for more information.

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "input")
MessageHandler messageHandler() {
    BroadcasterMessageHandler handler new BroadcasterMessageHandler(myProcessor);
    handler.setOutputChannel(output());
    return handler;
}
```

A service activator consists of 2 beans, a consumer and message handler; the message handler properties have to go on the handler bean itself.

<s>I created a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-3465) to have the handler detect the mis-configuration.</s>

In version 4.2, the `outputChannel` on the annotation is detected.